# Testing the number of attributes on an MVC controller method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, model-view-controller, mstest

I have an MVC controller that contains the following post method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[PermissionLevel(PermissionLevel.Manage)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAsync([FromBody] User user)
{
    user = await _usersService.CreateUserAsync(user);

    return Created($"{_microservices.Users}/{user.Id}", user);
}
```

I'm trying to unit test this controller (using MSTest), and one of the tests I want to make checks that the correct route and permission attributes have been applied to the method. I also want to ensure that **no other** attributes are present on the method, and I'm currently doing this by checking the count of attributes on the method:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void CreateUserAsync_HasTwoAttributes()
{
    int count = typeof(UsersController).GetMethod(nameof(UsersController.CreateUserAsync))
        .GetCustomAttributes()
        .Count();

    Assert.AreEqual(2, count);
}
```

This has worked fine elsewhere in my application (for properties), but when I run the tests the assert fails saying that there are actually 4 attributes on the method:

- `{System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute}`
- `{System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute}`
- `{Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute}`
- `{Permissions.Models.Filters.PermissionLevelAttribute}`

Where do the `AsyncStateMachine-` and `DebuggerStepThrough-` attributes come from? Is there a way I can not include them and only look at attributes that are explicitly declared on the controller method?

I'm using:

- .NET Core 2.1
- MSTest SDK 15.9.0

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Rather than checking the number of attributes, why don't test that it has the specific attributes.

Comment: Yeah, testing to make sure it doesnt have any other attributes is redundant in my eyes. As long as you test that the code executes the way you expect, it shouldn't matter if the run time adds an attribute to it or anything else. To summarise, just test that the attributes you have added (to make the code perform as you expect) are actually working. Your other unit tests that cover the logic should cover any other scenario.

Comment: @phuzi I'm doing that as well, in a different test, but I want a test that fails if any attributes other than the ones I specify are added.

Comment: @8ytan Why? Whats the point?

Comment: @KieranDevlin The reason I want a more general test for the number of attributes is if, for example, someone adds a `RouteAttribute` to the endpoint then the tests will continue to pass but the endpoint will be broken. I want to test that specific attributes are present and *only* those attributes.

Comment: Right, and your integration tests will fail (because the route has changed).

Comment: @8ytan This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should be testing expected behavior rather than implementation concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi To be fair, this is still regarded as behaviour as attributes can affect execution paths. But yes, its an XY problem.

Comment: @Nkosi I really just want to know where the extra attributes are coming from, what they're for, and if there's a way to exclude them.

Comment: @8ytan Those extra attributes are added at compile time. async adds the [`AsyncStateMachineAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute?view=netframework-4.8) and debug mode adds the [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @KieranDevlin I see your point, though I don't currently have an integration test that checks the full route of the method. Currently all the tests in the system call controller methods explicitly.

Comment: Anyway, even if you insist on going down this route (haha), you now know *why* and *what* the additional attributes are, and can therefore account for them in your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do the AsyncStateMachine- and DebuggerStepThrough- attributes come from?

Those extra attributes are added at compile time. async adds the [`AsyncStateMachineAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

> When a method (MethodName) has the Async or async modifier, the compiler emits IL that includes a state machine structure. This structure contains the code in the method. That IL also contains a stub method (MethodName) that calls into the state machine. The compiler adds the AsyncStateMachine attribute to the stub method so that tools can identify the corresponding state machine. Details of the emitted IL might change in future releases of the compilers.

and debug mode adds the [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute?view=netframework-4.8).